# Bibliography format with multiple citations from same book? (APA)

Tags: formatting, citations, apa

I'm writing a paper where I've included multiple citations from a book, each citation is not a direct quote from the text but rather a in-text citation so according to APA guidelines these citations should be at the end of the paraphrased text such as:

```
My text here blob blob blob (Rubin, 2013).
```

Since these citations do not include page numbers (direct quotes do, according to APA guidelines) and I have 3 (so far) when I insert a bibliography with Word these look like this:

```
Rubin, K. S. (2013). Essential SCRUM. Ann Arbor, Estados Unidos de América: Addison Wesley.
Rubin, K. S. (2013). Essential SCRUM. Ann Arbor, Estados Unidos de América: Addison Wesley.
Rubin, K. S. (2013). Essential SCRUM. Ann Arbor, Estados Unidos de América: Addison Wesley.
```

So, my question is if this is correct or should I include the page number from the book in the bibliography list? o should I do that in the citation as well even though they're not direct quotes?

Comment: Hi stigma, welcome to writing.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. While this question is on topic here, due to our current low activity you might have better luck getting an answer over at [academia.se]. Good luck and happy writing!

Comment: @linksassin Thank you! will post it there instead.